# How to setup password for elasticsearch users?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to enable security for my ES cloud. I am following these instructions:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/configuring-security.html

and I am stuck at point 6. When I try to run `bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive` I got error:

```
Failed to determine the health of the cluster running at http://XXX:9200
Unexpected response code [503] from calling GET http://XXX:9200/_cluster/health?pretty
Cause: master_not_discovered_exception

It is recommended that you resolve the issues with your cluster before running elasticsearch-setup-passwords.
It is very likely that the password changes will fail when run against an unhealthy cluster.

Do you want to continue with the password setup process [y/N]
```

I try to check my ES instance state:

```
curl http://XXX:9200/_cluster/health?pretty
```

and get

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "security_exception",
        "reason" : "missing authentication credentials for REST request [/_cluster/health?pretty]",
        "header" : {
          "WWW-Authenticate" : "Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""
        }
      }
    ],
    "type" : "security_exception",
    "reason" : "missing authentication credentials for REST request [/_cluster/health?pretty]",
    "header" : {
      "WWW-Authenticate" : "Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""
    }
  },
  "status" : 401
}
```

So, looks like I cant setup a password because I can`t authenticate :) ?

Comment: have you tried to add `-u username` in curl?

Comment: I don`t know which user I can use. I tried to use `elastic` user, but I don`t know a password. And cant setup new password :)

Comment: I see the same issue, no matter what I do I can not set the password. Setting up ElasticSearch is extremely buggy.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is the official [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/configuring-security.html) for setting up security for Elasticsearch

step 1:
`cd /usr/share/elasticsearch/`

step 2:

```
sudo bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords auto
```

or

```
sudo bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive
```

> auto - Uses randomly generated passwords interactive - Uses passwords
> entered by a user

The above commands can help you to setup password

Comment: As I described above - it can`t setup password

Comment: @prosto.vint  Your cluster isn't in a healthy state, so it is not possible for the tool to set the user passwords.

Comment: @prosto.vint  I think you need to set host   network.host: 127.0.0.1  in config/elasticsearch.yaml

Comment: HI @HariharanAR I need to direct update the password at the initial phase and not want to go through generating random password to provide access to user through rest API. please help.

Comment: For anyone else ```/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords auto``` but it doesn't work. ```Cause: Cluster state has not been recovered yet, cannot write to the [null] index```

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me in Windows.

Ensure elastic node is up and running. In a separate prompt, from elasticsearch/bin, run the below command

*elasticsearch-setup-passwords auto -u "http://localhost:9200"*

Elastic will ask you for proceeding with the setup of auto generated password. Once you proceed with yes, you will be provide with the password for elastic/kibana/beats etc.

Answer (score 1):

for the windows run the elk in cmd
open other cmd and past the command where the elk in folder

```
bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords auto
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found that the Magento stores the credential in an XML file and it can be found in base directory:

```
+\magento\vendor\magento\module-elasticsearch-7\etc\config.xml. Please update your elastic password instead of XXXXXX and also in case you have chosen a different version of elastic, the location would be different.
    -->
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
        <default>
            <catalog>
                <search>
                    <engine>elasticsearch7</engine>
                    <elasticsearch7_server_hostname>localhost</elasticsearch7_server_hostname>
                    <elasticsearch7_server_port>9200</elasticsearch7_server_port>
                    <elasticsearch7_index_prefix>magento2</elasticsearch7_index_prefix>
                    <elasticsearch7_enable_auth>1</elasticsearch7_enable_auth>
                    <elasticsearch7_username>elastic</elasticsearch7_username>
                    <elasticsearch7_password>XXXXXXXXXXX</elasticsearch7_password>nfog              
                    <elasticsearch7_server_timeout>15</elasticsearch7_server_timeout>
                    <elasticsearch7_minimum_should_match/>
                </search>
            </catalog>
        </default>
    </config>
```

Answer (score 0):

open cmd in your bin folder
`D:\software\elasticsearch-8.8.0\bin`
and hit `>elasticsearch.bat`

open another cmd in your bin folder
`D:\software\elasticsearch-8.8.0\bin`
and hit `>elasticsearch-reset-password -u elastic`